# How to cache a file using source

Tags: bash, shell, source

Is there a bash command like `source` except it will only source a file once for a given shell?

for example:

```
source_cached foo.sh    # runs as normal
source_cached foo.sh    # would not load foo.sh a second time
```

since the foo.sh path has already been sourced, it would not source it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called an "include guard". You can see an example on SO by Jonathan Leffler at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518684/6512983.

```bsh
if [ -z "$B_SH_INCLUDED" ]
then
    B_SH_INCLUDED=yes
    ...rest of original contents of b.sh
fi
```

Essentially you define a variable in the file you've included, but check for its existence beforehand and return prematurely if it's already defined.